# if statement for components - template

Tags: component, bootstrap

i use a Solution for my Custom Bootstrap Template.

Here is my idea: If a certain component open in the frontend, they add the word "-fluid" to my containter css class.

but i don't know how i can check if the certain component open in the frontend.

Any Idea?

Regards,

Comment: In the frontend vs the backend?

Answer (score 2):

```
$component = JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('option');

if ($component === 'com_example')
{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: wow, wow ,wow! Great Thank you! That's it!